# Alias on table column gives undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In rails 3.2.13 with a postgres database, one of my app's tables gives an error if any column is aliased.

This only happens on one table. It is the longest named table (in case that's relevant). In the console:

```
MyEngine::SpeciesValuation.select('my_engine_species_valuations.id as ida').first.ida
```

(very same outcome when the column name is not prefixed by the table name)

gives:

```
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `ida' for nil:NilClass
```

Any alias name on any column in this table produces the same error. Except if I use the column name as the alias name. E.G. "id as id" or "count(id) as id" is ok.

Note that although the error says 'nil:NilClass', the query does return an object of the expected type, it just doesn't respond to the alias name.

Comment: Try `MyEngine::SpeciesValuation.select('my_engine_species_valuations.id as ida').first["ida"]`

Comment: What happens when you add attr_accessor :ida to the model class?

Comment: Vimsha, that was it. Thank you so much. If you add an answer I can accept

Comment: mu - the error shown in misleading. The alias is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `MyEngine::SpeciesValuation.select('my_engine_species_valuations.id as ida').first` is not returning an object.  Can you paste the SQL that is generated?

I just tried something similar in one of my projects and it works just fine:

```
Photo.select("id as idp").first.idp
  Photo Load (0.4ms)  SELECT id as idp FROM "photos" LIMIT 1
  => "c0f2d534-d16e-11e2-9443-28cfe9162c87"
```

Comment: Wow.  What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: It's Rails version 3.2.13